# How to use partition in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to find out and came to the conclusion that partition should used for this task. But, I've never used this before.

I have a table like:

```
id  status
1    3
2    1
1    4
3    2
3    3
1    5
```

I want to get list of all id's that don't have status as 5. Please help!!

Comment: what? this is not difficult and partition is probably an overkill.. what have you tried so far? this bloody homework again aye!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as possible I think this would work for you. Your example could be more specific so I hope this is what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM table_name
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE status = 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ID
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT( CASE status WHEN 5 THEN 1 END ) = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't need partition to perform this task. All you have to do is 
select id from 
where status not in ('5')

Comment: But with that I will get everything except the last row. But what I really want is ids  2,3